# Why the Bresenham's algorithm does not work for those two points?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry, offline

I am using the Bresenham algorithm from wikipedia:

```
 plotLine(x0,y0, x1,y1)
      dx = x1 - x0
      dy = y1 - y0
      D = 2*dy - dx
      y = y0

     for x from x0 to x1
        plot(x,y)
        if D > 0
           y = y + 1
           D = D - 2*dx
        end if
        D = D + 2*dy
```

I have the following two points:

```
P1 = (10, 120) and P2 = (18, 117)
```

I wrote a C program to run the algorithm and I got as output:

```
ePlot the following points: 
10, 120
11, 120
12, 120
13, 120
14, 120
15, 120
16, 120
17, 120
```

Which is totally wrong, is there any other version of this algorithm which works for this scenario or it does not exist?

Comment: The algorithm as written is only for the case $\Delta x > \Delta y > 0$. In your case you have $\Delta y < 0$, which is why it does not work. See the complete algorithm under "All cases" instead.

Answer (score 2):

Like Rahul said that algorithm is only in the case where $0 \lt \Delta y \lt \Delta x$.

So you need to adjust the coordinates to fit within that.

There are 8 cases:

1. $0 \lt \Delta y \lt \Delta x$ the normal base case
2. $0 \lt \Delta x \lt \Delta y$ swap x and y except for the drawPixel call.
3. $\Delta x \lt 0 \lt \Delta y$ and $|\Delta y < \Delta x|$ use case 1 but negate $\Delta x$ and instead of counting from x0 to x1 you count from x1 to x0
4. $\Delta x \lt 0 \lt \Delta y$ and $|\Delta x \lt \Delta y|$ use case 2 but negate $\Delta x$ and instead of counting from x0 to x1 you count from x1 to x0

The remaining cases have $\Delta y \lt 0$ so swap the 2 points and it will fall within the previous 4 cases.